# Relation ManyToOne - Unrecognized field of my entity

Tags: php, symfony

I'm doing a simple Blog engine on SYmfony2.

I have 2 entity Comment and Article who are related with a ManyToOne on Comment side.

```
// Comment.php
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Am\BlogBundle\Entity\Article")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
*/
private $article;
```

When I try to delete an Article, I would like to delete all comments related to this article.

```
//Am/BlogBundle/Controller/BlogController.php

public function delArticleAction(Article $article)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()
               ->getEntityManager();

    $list_tags = $em->getRepository('AmBlogBundle:Tag')
                       ->findAll();

    $list_comments = $em->getRepository('AmBlogBundle:Comment')
                       ->findBy(array('article_id'=>$article->getId()));                   

    //In order to delete an article, we have to remove each object linked to an Article
    foreach($list_tags as $value){
        $article->removeTags($value);
    }

    foreach($list_comments as $value){
        //We delete all the comments of an article
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($value); 
        $em->flush();
    }

    // We remove the Article
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->remove($article); 
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('AmBlogBundle:Blog:delArticle.html.twig');
}
```

In fact, I would like to get only the Comment tied to my Article and goes the same with Tags :/

I don't know what am I doing wrong ? Some help would be nice :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add onDelete="CASCADE" in your entity definition and this will be added to the foreign key in the database, so when you delete an Article, it will cascade delete related comments automatically.

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Am\BlogBundle\Entity\Article")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 */
private $article;
```

Comment: Ok but I also got an entity Tags linked to my entity Article it will also remove all the tags tied to the article right ? Nevermind I answered myself =D Thank you